# css li image arrange jump position

Tags: css

I have problem with my css img when I assign on `<ul>` can anybody tell me what happen with it ?

**CSS**

```
<style>
.contain {
    width: 740px;
    height: auto;
    margin-top: 10px;
}
.contain ul li img {
    border: 1px solid #999;
    width: 127px;
    height: 180px;
}
.contain ul li {
    float:left;
    text-decoration: none;
    list-style-type: none;
    margin-top: 15px;
    margin-right: 8px;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    margin-left: 7px;
    display: block;
}
</style>
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="contain">
    <ul>
       <li><img name="Name" src="img/a.jpg" width="127" height="180" alt=\"imgName"></li>
        <li><img name="Name" src="img/a.jpg" width="127" height="180" alt=\"imgName"></li>
        <li><img name="Name" src="img/a.jpg" width="127" height="180" alt=\"imgName"></li>
        <li><img name="Name" src="img/a.jpg" width="127" height="180" alt=\"imgName"></li>
        <li><img name="Name" src="img/a.jpg" width="127" height="180" alt=\"imgName"></li>
        <li><img name="Name" src="img/a.jpg" width="127" height="180" alt=\"imgName"></li>
        <li><img name="Name" src="img/a.jpg" width="127" height="180" alt=\"imgName"></li>
        <li><img name="Name" src="img/a.jpg" width="127" height="180" alt=\"imgName"></li>
        <li><img name="Name" src="img/a.jpg" width="127" height="180" alt=\"imgName"></li>       
        <li><img name="Name" src="img/a.jpg" width="127" height="180" alt=\"imgName"></li>               
    </ul>
```

but the img output like below:

[image]

as you can see in the second line become one image left and in third row img for sure have 4, so why images are not ordered in 2 rows of 5 imges each ?

Comment: sorry for the wrong word.

Comment: is actually. why the img do not order by 5 in two row only. thx for the attention

Comment: seems to work fine for me http://fiddle.jshell.net/55gFU/

Comment: that why i am confusing, why the output come out like that

Comment: thx for u guy, i found the problem real is.

Answer (score 0):

The output coming out like that because your margin, especially left and right...delete them ..http://fiddle.jshell.net/55gFU/1/

Comment: did this answer to you question?